# Python threading: will Event.set() really notify every waiting thread

Tags: python, multithreading, events, wait

If I have a `threading.Event` and the following two lines of code:

```
event.set()
event.clear()
```

and I have some threads who are waiting for that event.

My question is related to what happens when calling the `set()` method:

- Can I be ABSOLUTELY sure that all the waiting thread(s) will be notified? (i.e. `Event.set()` "notifies" the threads)
- Or could it happen that those two lines are executed so quickly after each other, that some threads might still be waiting? (i.e. `Event.wait()` polls the event's state, which might be already "cleared" again)

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 16):

In the internals of Python, an event is implemented with a [`Condition()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects) object.

When calling the `event.set()` method, the [`notify_all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.notify_all) of the condition is called (after getting the lock to be sure to be not interrupted), then all the threads receive the notification (the lock is released only when all the threads are notified), so you can be sure that all the threads will effectively be notified.

Now, clearing the event just after the notification is not a problem.... until you do not want to check the event value in the waiting threads with an `event.is_set()`, but you only need this kind of check if you were waiting with a timeout.

Examples :

pseudocode that works :

```
#in main thread
event = Event()
thread1(event)
thread2(event)
...
event.set()
event.clear()

#in thread code
...
event.wait()
#do the stuff
```

pseudocode that may not work :

```
#in main thread
event = Event()
thread1(event)
thread2(event)
...
event.set()
event.clear()

#in thread code
...
while not event.is_set():
   event.wait(timeout_value)
#do the stuff
```

Edited : in python >= 2.7 you can still wait for an event with a timeout and be sure of the state of the event :

```
event_state = event.wait(timeout)
while not event_state:
    event_state = event.wait(timeout)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 2.7 the return value from `event.wait()` is unreliable if you're specifying a timeout. See https://bugs.python.org/issue13502

Answer (score 15):

It's easy enough to verify that things work as expected (**Note:** this is Python 2 code, which will need adapting for Python 3):

```
import threading

e = threading.Event()
threads = []

def runner():
    tname = threading.current_thread().name
    print 'Thread waiting for event: %s' % tname
    e.wait()
    print 'Thread got event: %s' % tname

for t in range(100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=runner)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

raw_input('Press enter to set and clear the event:')
e.set()
e.clear()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print 'All done.'
```

If you run the above script and it terminates, all should be well :-) Notice that a hundred threads are waiting for the event to be set; it's set and cleared straight away; all threads should see this and should terminate (though not in any definite order, and the "All done" can be printed anywhere after the "Press enter" prompt, not just at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3+**

### It's easier to check that it works

```
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock() # just to sync printing
e = threading.Event()
threads = []

def runner():
    tname = threading.current_thread().name
    with lock:
        print('Thread waiting for event ', tname)
    e.wait()
    with lock:
        print('Thread got event: ', tname)

for t in range(8): # Create 8 threads could be 100's
    t = threading.Thread(target=runner)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

time.sleep(1) # force wait until set/clear
e.set()
e.clear()
for t in threads:
    t.join()    
    
print('Done')
```